# Automatically get pre-tax funds in a self directed Traditional IRA

Tags: united-states, taxes, tax-deduction, ira, self-directed-ira

A company I am employed with doesn't offer a IRA. Self directed Traditional IRA isn't a problem, but I would like the pre-tax contributions to come out of my paycheck, instead of waiting till the next year to make an IRA deduction.

Is it possible for the company to facilitate this?

Comment: I think you need to ask the company that question. It isn't impossible, but their payroll system may not be flexible enough to do it.

Answer (score 1):

You can lower your withholding in anticipation of making the deduction on your Form 1040 at the end of the year. This will have the same effect without much hassle.  Just compute the correction and give your employer and new W-4.  You'll still need to make the deposits to your IRA periodically, which I guess is a minor hassle, but, as noted in another answer, your IRA custodian might help you out there by arranging a regularly scheduled electronic withdrawal from you bank account.

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is probably to combine a direct-deposit from your employer with regular IRA contributions from your bank account controlled by your broker.  Brokers will probably do a much better job in particular making sure you don't exceed your annual limit.  They also will be better setup to automatically allocate those funds according to your instructions so it won't just sit in cash.

As an example, here is Vanguard's program

https://personal.vanguard.com/us/insights/article/automatic-ira-contributions-012014